# android Am.jar add permissions on rooted device

Tags: android, jar, apk, android-permissions, android-framework

I have a rooted device, and I noticed that the `am` command in `adb` cannot perform all its tasks since it does NOT have "**signature**" permission.

How do you suppose that happens?......... I noticed this behavior on other devices as well (rooted and non rooted)
On an emulator `Am.jar` seems to have this permission.
Is there any way I can modify the Am.jar (or the `app_process` that runs it) so that it would have the same signature as the systems'.
As I mentioned, my device is also *rooted*.

Thanks

Comment: First, it's possible that you are not actually running `am` as root.  Beyond that, android was never designed with the idea of being "rooted", and as you are finding, that can be far from a direct route to obtaining android-level permissions.  Perhaps the distinction of behavior you are seeing on the emulator has to do with something else, such as the ro.debuggable and/or ro.secure properties.  IIRC there's also a property which specifically specifies an emulator.

Comment: Thanks Chris. In this case it does not have anything to do with the fact that it's an emulator (I debugged the code). What I see happens because of permission issues. I am wondering if there is any way to provide a "signature" permission to an app on a rooted phone

Comment: I think you may be mistaken in dismissing the emulator's uniqueness without making an effort to figure out why it acts differently. Fundamentally, `am` is not an *app*.

Comment: I am debugging the platform itself so I can see where the permission check occurs. My guess is that app_process that runs Am.jar doesn't have this permission (either that or Am itself are not signed with platform key)

Comment: You still do not understand. Signing applies to *apps* and this **is not an app**.  When an *app* launches, zygote forks off a new instance and specializes it, changing the userid to limit to the permissions granted at unix-level and bequeathing standing and identify for IPC-level permissions - no exec() family function is ever called.  But when the shell forks and calls exec() to load the `am` program you have a much cleaner slate.  The unix permissions are those of the running user (root or shell) but there's essentially no standing with the IPC system for things enforced at that level.

Comment: Some Android permissions are enforced at the Linux level (INTERNET is the classic example), but not all. When Zygote forks a new process with all necessary features (gid,uid, etc.) it has no info about pure Android permissions. These permissions are handled only by the PackageManager (not Linux). Whether app_process (which launches the Am.jar) has root/system/user access makes no difference to the permission enforcement in PackageManager since this is a pure Linux process. What mystifies me is how, when running on emulator, this permission is granted for this pure Linux process

Comment: Indeed, this is unlikely to concern unix level permissions, which is why running as root probably won't help (though you've never confirmed that you are).  The problem you don't seem to be grasping is that **there is no application "package"** (as a security identity)  to attach android-level permissions to so that PackageManager could recognize this entity and grant them, for the repeated reason **that `am` is not an app**.  Again, I'll suggest that you look into why the emulator itself may behave differently - for example, it may simply allow things devices don't irrespective of permissions.

Comment: As it stands, your question is incomplete.  You need to state *which specific tasks* that work on the emulator are not working on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, as @Chris mentioned, that the problem isn't signing permissions.
When running `Am` on the emulator it runs as a system process. On devices it doesn't.
If I run this command as root then all permissions are granted (even signature).

Comment: It does not run as a system process, but the emulator gives you a root shell to begin with.